# Unrecognized behaviour of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char str[]={'1','2','3'},*p;
  p=str;
  printf("%c",p);
  return 0;
}
```

Output-@.

Shouldn't it print 1 or `%c` might be the reason?

Comment: It will print a character representation of a `str` address casted to `char`. That's it.

Comment: `p` refers to the pointer i.e. its memory address. You should dereference it to get what it is pointing to: `*p`

Comment: Ok so if i use %s then it will print 123 right???

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Actually, since `printf()` is varargs, the behavior is undefined when the argument type doesn't match (some exceptions exist, but none for `char */int`).

Comment: @EOF, well, didn't get that deep yet :)

Answer (score 4):

To print the value at a pointer (i.e., 1, as you had expected), you got to dereference that pointer. In your case,

```
printf("%c",p);
```

should be

```
printf("%c", *p);
```

FWIW, `printf("%c",p);` will invoke undefined behavior as the supplied argument type will be a mismatch with the supplied format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

p is a pointer.

You want `printf("%c",*p);`